# Git does not update while doing git clone

Tags: upgrade, git, macos

I want to update my git version to the latest (2.38.1).

This is my version:

```
git --version
git version 2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)
```

I am following the [guide](https://git-scm.com/downloads) "Git via Git" and so I type:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git
```

But if I re-type:

```
git --version
git version 2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)
```

As you can see the version seems not to be updated correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merely checking out a source code repository will not update the installed software on your system. You would have to build and install the software, which is a process described in the project's documentation (see, e.g., the [INSTALL](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL) file).

However, unless you want the most bleeding edge unstable development version of the project, it's often easier to update software like this using your system's package manager.

On macOS, the base system uses an older `git` version (2.37.1), which will unlikely change soon.  Instead, I suggest you use [the Homebrew package manager](https://brew.sh) to install the latest version of `git`.  There is no issue with having `git` installed in two separate locations on the same system. When setting up the Homebrew package manager, it will ensure that its versions of tools get priority over the base system's versions of the same tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a macOS user. Do you know how you have installed git, did you used `brew`?

If so, try the following:

```
brew update
brew upgrade git
```

The following will only get the source of git and will not install or update git on your local machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git
```